# How to pass a function in React's Context?

Tags: reactjs

I have created a context (CharacterContext) which exports class CharacterProvider, which itself passes to the consumers several objects in the state. I would like to also pass a REST call function getCharacter. I was thinking about passing it like this:

```
export class CharacterProvider extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            name: "",
            ...
            getCharacter: this.getCharacter(),
        }
    }

    getCharacter = (id) => {
        console.log("Getting the character...")
        CharacterDataService.getCharacterById(id)
            .then(
                response => {
                    console.log(response);
                    this.setState({
                        name: response.data.username,
                        ...
                    });
                }
            )
    }

render() {
        return (
            <CharacterContext.Provider
                value={this.state}>
               {
                   this.props.children
               }
            </CharacterContext.Provider>
        )
    }

export const CharacterConsumer = CharacterContext.Consumer
```

However I guess this would only fire the function and pass the result. What is the correct way to pass the function? So far the element has received the function in the props like this:

```
export default class Loader extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            names: [/* filled by an API call */]
        }
        ....

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="row mt-3">
                    <div className="col"></div>
                    {
                        Object.values(this.state.names).map( (name) => {
                            return(
                            <div className="col-1" key={name}>

                                <button className="btn btn-info" onClick={() =>
                                    this.props.getCharacter(Object.keys(this.state.names).find(key => this.state.names[key] === name))} key={name}>
                                {name}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        )})
                    }
                    <div className="col"></div>

                </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I would like to pass the function from the Context as it will be used in several different components too. I have used the contest to pass values succesfully but I am still looking for the correct way to pass functions, and I have found not tutorial that would really help me with that so far.

Sorry if the code is wobbly, I have just recently started with ReactJS and JS itself.

Edit:

I am passing the provider like this:

```
App.js
...
render() {
        return (
            <div className="App container-fluid">
                <CharacterProvider>
                    <Loader/>
                </CharacterProvider>
...
```

Comment: Have you also considered using `Consumer` component instead of `this.context`? It is another option and may make more sense to you syntactically, if the below answer does not work.

Comment: Also, if you plan to get information out of multiple different context objects inside of a single component (perhaps not now but in the future), you may want to go with the `Consumer` component approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't using context correctly. You need to render the `Provider` and wrap it in the hierarchy

```
export class CharacterProvider extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            name: "",
            ...
            getCharacter: this.getCharacter(),
        }
    }

    getCharacter = (id) => {
        console.log("Getting the character...")
        CharacterDataService.getCharacterById(id)
            .then(
                response => {
                    console.log(response);
                    this.setState({
                        name: response.data.username,
                        ...
                    });
                }
            )
         render() {
              return (
                   <CharacterContext.Provider value={this.state}>{children}</CharacterContext.Provider>
              )
          }
    }

export const CharacterConsumer = CharacterContext.Consumer
```

Not you render this `CharacterProvider` in the hierarchy like

```
return (
    <CharacterProvider>
         <Loader/>
    </CharacterProvider>
)
```

Now you need to specify the contextTypes for Loader and use the function from `this.context`

```
export default class Loader extends React.Component { 
    static contextTypes = CharacterContext
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            names: [/* filled by an API call */]
        }
        ....

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="row mt-3">
                    <div className="col"></div>
                    {
                        Object.values(this.state.names).map( (name) => {
                            return(
                            <div className="col-1" key={name}>

                                <button className="btn btn-info" onClick={() =>
                                    this.context.getCharacter(Object.keys(this.state.names).find(key => this.state.names[key] === name))} key={name}>
                                {name}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        )})
                    }
                    <div className="col"></div>

                </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, contextType was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!